# Detecting whether a line (with several points) is by itself, or connected to another line

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, gis, shapefile

I am writing code to detect whether a line (with multiple points, these lines have curves)  is part of a road network. If there is a road with no way to get to it (basically isolated) I need to flag it.

See the below screenshot

[image]

While scanning through the road network, the isolated lines should be flagged.

**My thoughts on a solution**
**UPDATE Jan 14th/2014:**
Tt works! It is however WAY too slow. It takes 30 minutes to run!

I start by sorting from left to right. I then add the first item in the list to XYPoints "network" list/hashset. It checks every XYPoint of every line for a connection (same point), and then adds all its points to the "network" and remove it from the list of lines (since it's already been checked, no need to check it again).

If the polyline isn't connected to the main network, it will still be residing in my original list of all the roads at the end.

Okay, code snippet, I'll keep updating this as I make progress, feel free to add some thoughts:

```
while (true)
{
    int numOflinesBeforeChecking = polylinez.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < polylinez.Count; i++)
    {
        //scan through each point of each polyline
        foreach (XYPoints xyp in polylinez[i].XYpoints)
        {
            //bool foundAvertice = false;
            if (listOfEndPoints.Contains(xyp))
            {
                //add them as endpoints
                foreach (XYPoints verifiedXYs in polylinez[i].XYpoints)
                {
                    listOfEndPoints.Add(verifiedXYs);
                }
                //add them to the network
                for (var g = 0; g < (polylinez[i].XYpoints.Count - 1); g++)
                {
                    mainHighwaylines.Add(new Line2D(polylinez[i].XYpoints[g], polylinez[i].XYpoints[g + 1]));
                }
                polylinez.RemoveAt(i);
                break; //break out of scanning XYPoints of an individual line/road, hit this again!
            } //end if

        } //end foreach XYPoint loop

    } //end for i loop

    //clearly there are no more lines
    if (numOflinesBeforeChecking == polylinez.Count)
    {
        break;
    }
} //end infinite loop

//check for intersections here
//mainHighway Lines has been generated, now let's check them for intersections
while (true)
{
    int numOflinesBeforeChecking = polylinez.Count;
    for (var i = 0; i < polylinez.Count; i++)
    {
        //smallLines relates to each individual polyline, seperated into even smaller lines
        List<Line2D> smallLines = new List<Line2D>();
        for (var g = 0; g < (polylinez[i].XYpoints.Count - 1); g++)
        {
            smallLines.Add(new Line2D(polylinez[i].XYpoints[g], polylinez[i].XYpoints[g + 1]));
        }
        bool intersectionFound = false;
        foreach (Line2D line in smallLines)
        {
            bool lineIntersection = false;
            foreach (Line2D mainHighwayline in mainHighwaylines)
            {
                if (line.intersectsLine(mainHighwayline))
                {
                    intersectionFound = true;
                    lineIntersection = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (lineIntersection)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (intersectionFound)
        {
            for (var g = 0; g < (polylinez[i].XYpoints.Count - 1); g++)
            {
                mainHighwaylines.Add(new Line2D(polylinez[i].XYpoints[g], polylinez[i].XYpoints[g + 1]));
            }
            polylinez.RemoveAt(i);
        }

    }
    //clearly there are no more lines
    if (numOflinesBeforeChecking == polylinez.Count)
    {
        break;
    }

}
```

**What I need**

Improvements on how to make this faster! The second infinite loop takes most of the time.

The second infinite loop with a break checks to see if there's intersections (they might not have shared end points, they might just intersect). I keep it in an infinite loop in case there's new data added.

Making the second major loop (checking for intersection loop) infinite with an if statement makes it go from 6 minutes to 30. However it is necessary to catch certain false positives.

Comment: The simplest thing that comes to my mind is to group lines that intersect at any point. Then for each group check if any line in the group touches the edge. Am I missing something?

Comment: @BartoszKP the problem is defining the lines. If you zoom in into this picture, you would see that all the roads are very intricate (= formed by many lines in different directions); if the roads are not accurately defined by the lines, the intersection calculations wouldn't be accurate either. Also, it does not seem possible to conclude what the main network is just by performing a geometrical analysis.

Comment: @varocarbas I guess I'm not getting whether we have line objects or pixels here (not familiar to `gis`) :)

Comment: @BartoszKP Actually I am not too familiar with gis either; but I am pretty familiar with adapting mathematical/ideal conditions to real situations and I know the huge hassle that is usually involved. And this picture is certainly scary ;)

Comment: These are line objects, I do have access to all the points in each line. I tried breaking them up into smaller lines, however this flags the last line of something like a dead end street as an isolated line.

Comment: @EvanParsons this is what I meant with intrincate: you cannot reduce these roads to just one line (not even a few lines) and thus you shouldn't perform intersection calculations (otherwise the computational expense and the level of uncertainty would be huge).

Comment: @EvanParsons I think you need to define more precisely what is the main network, and what constitutes an isolated line. Also, what is a "line" - in your picture how many lines are there?

Comment: A line is a road. It's made up of several points since roads have curves. There are around 90,000 lines to go through (around 100 XY points on average). The main network is the "interconnectedness" of all the roads. An isolated road is a road that you would have to drive through water or off road to get to (there's no way to drive to it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard (,continuous) geometrical approach does not seem to be applicable here. From your picture, the roads are too intrincate (and thus very difficult or impossible to be replaced by just one line (or a bunch of them)) and the situation to be modelled (being part of the network) too imprecisely-defined, to rely on simplifications.

The only accurate-enough approach I can come up with for this problem is checking whether the given roads have common points with the main network or not.

Main ideas:

1. Storing all the points defining the main network; that is, all the
   points of each road forming part of it. This collection will be
   constantly updated with each new road decided to be part of the
   network (as explained in the point below).
2. Analysing each road by checking all their defining points and confirming whether they are part of the main network or not (eventually, by accounting for some "tolerance error"). A secondary
   collection will be started here where all the roads connected to the
   road being analysed will be included (once the analysed road is
   considered connected, all these secondary roads will automatically
   be considered connected too and vice versa).

Logically, this is an in-the-worst-scenario-possible approach; the more information you have, the more simplifications would be applicable and the less brute-force the calculations might become. But if your input data looks like the one in the picture, I wouldn't be too optimistic on this front.

Comment: Have an upvote from me, it sent me down the right path (see original question, I've been updating it)

Comment: @JDB hi. I have been target of a multi downvoting process. I thought that this answer was part of the batch; if not sorry.

Comment: @EvanParsons Thanks. But you are free to do whatever you want; this wasn't with you. But with a batch-downvoter (well... actually, I have got much more upvotes than downvotes)... I don't like this things and just intend to fight them by intending to discuss with this people and understanding why on the hell they do that (with someone like me who does not care about point and who has zero problems to delete an answer; actually, I was really close to delete this one). Sorry again, I have deleted my comment.

Comment: @JDB Thanks for the advice. I have flagged various questions (although the final result was to my favour; the downvoter suddenly became an upvoter (or other person, not sure) and 1ed some of my answers). I guess that I am more a fight the fire with fire kind of person, much more here in SO. Perhaps I am a bit extremist but I think that this kind of behaviours shouldn't be controlled via "we can catch you" (with an implicit "what you are doing is more or less understandable"); but more with "what on the hell is wrong with you to have such a senseless behaviour?". SO users should care about...

Comment: @JDB... building a strong community based on knowledge and open discussions to solve any issue. People thinking that votes matter at all (other than for showing up what is right) and that are weapons that can be used to damage others are so lost that should be aware about it. Also bear in mind that I do attract quite a few of this people, just because of being honest and saying things openly. Some of this people have just got offended because I said them "this is wrong" at some point or equivalent -> (not because of being myself) but this is still more censurable IMO. Anyway... thanks.

Comment: @JDB You might be right. But I cannot be patient with pointless behaviours; mainly because of thinking that might provoke a damage somewhere else. On the other hand, I do have to refrain myself from doing what I consider right in SO (and will certainly do it). I do understand that most of people here think more like you than like me and thus showing "my behaviour" is not doing the right thing (also I have promised a moderator to stop doing this kind of things :)). I will try a bit harder in the future, thanks again for your advice.

Comment: Finished up the project today basically using this approach, thank you sir.

Comment: @EvanParsons No problem. Hopefully it will also be helpful for future readers.